# How to install phantom.js in my server

Tags: linux, webserver, phantomjs

I am having Linux based server on shared hosting from hostgator.I need to install the phantom.js but I couldn't find help anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to ask HostGator if they will install PhantomJS for you on their shared environment or you can rent a Linux virtual private server and install it yourself.